# Flutter Blue Sending Quite Large File from BLE device to App

Tags: flutter, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, data-transfer

I need to send a file .txt from a device to my app (worst case almost 2mb). The BLE device divide the file into packages. I don't know if my method is correct, but I create a loop of characteristic.write/characteristic.read telling everytime what package the device has to send.
Here's my code:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < packNumber.length; i++) {
        initialValue = '9,50,100,$i,0,$checksumId,0/';
        await characteristic
         .write(utf8.encode(initialValue)).then((wValue) async {
                 await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 100)).then((value) async {
                       await characteristic.read().then((rValue) {
                            //do something with rVlaue
                       });
                 });
        });
   }
```

It works, but is it the best solution? And in case how can I speed up the transfer (for now I have to set a delay before reading, waiting for characteristic.write to finish)?

Thank you guys

Comment: Firstly BLE is not recommended for such file transfers. You're better off with classic BT & something like an SPP or an OBEX protocol. Like you said BLE can send 20? bytes or so per characteristic and this complicates things, there's also a delay between each send/receive too for keeping energy consumption low. Just not a good idea. But if you really want to do it, this is pretty much it.

Answer (score 0):

You should change the remote device to send notifications instead of using reads. That gives maximum throughput.

Comment: Could u give me an example please?

Comment: If you don't know what that means, I suggest you to read some basic introduction to BLE and GATT. That should make it clear.

Answer (score 0):

The default Maximum Transfer Unit (MTU) in most BLE devices are 20 bytes of payload (plus L2CAP = 4 Bytes & ATT Header = 3 Bytes). You should try requesting MTU in your device. With Bluetooth 5.x, max MTU could be 512 but this depends on your microcontroller or any BLE devices. In nRF52840 max MTU I can get is 247.

```dart
// (Android Only) On iOS, MTU is negotiated automatically
// Automatically chooses the highest possible MTU when sets to 512.
// Got 247 in nRF52840
if (Platform.isAndroid) await device!.requestMtu(512);
```